# 500 Internal Server Error when Trying to Save Menu

Tags: menus, 500-internal-error

I've got a few dozen pages in my menu. When I try to add new pages to the menu, then Firefox gives me the "connecting" message int eh tab and it eventually stops after a few minutes and gives me an 500 Internal Server Error. The problem is intermittent. I'll be able to add a few pages to the menu without a problem and then run into the error again and lose many of the menu items that I had saved.

I use HostGator and I have the dedicated server option. I submitted a ticket to HostGator to work on it. I'm running WP 3.1

I looked at the server's error log and saw these entries:

> [Mon Jul 11 14:40:42 2011] [error] [client 74.202.255.243]
>   SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script
>   "/home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
>
> [Mon Jul 11 14:40:38 2011] [error] [client 216.110.94.228]
>   SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script
>   "/home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
>
> [Mon Jul 11 14:40:36 2011] [error] [client 74.202.255.243]
>   SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script
>   "/home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/edit.php" is smaller than min_uid,
>   referer: http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/
>
> [Mon Jul 11 14:27:31 2011] [error] [client 74.202.255.243]
>   SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script
>   "/home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
>
> [Mon Jul 11 14:27:30 2011] [error] [client 74.202.255.243]
>   SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script
>   "/home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
>
> [Mon Jul 11 14:27:22 2011] [error] [client 74.202.255.243]
>   SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script
>   "/home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
>
> [Mon Jul 11 14:27:19 2011] [error] [client 74.202.255.243]
>   SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script
>   "/home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/index.php" is smaller than min_uid
>
> [Mon Jul 11 14:27:18 2011] [error] [client 74.202.255.243]
>   SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script
>   "/home/mysite/public_html/wp-admin/nav-menus.php" is smaller than
>   min_uid

Any suggestions on what to do? Could [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/saving-nav-menu-crashes-server?replies=4) have something to do with it?

Thank you!

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a work around so I can save menus as long as I want.

I used the [Gecka Submenu Pro](http://gecka-apps.com/wordpress-plugins/gecka-submenu-pro/) plugin. It worked great. I wish that I had found this solution 2 weeks ago.

(No, I do not work for Gecka. I'm not receiving anything from them. They didn't ask me to post this.)

Answer (score 1):

That error, **SoftException in Application.cpp:303: UID of script** ... **is smaller than min_uid** is because the files are owned by the wrong owner, normally root, and UID (user IDs) less `min_uid` are not allowed (and root is typically 0).  I'm not sure how that happened on HostGator, or what tools you have to remedy it, but you need to make sure the files are owned by your user and your group and I think you will see this error go away.

If you have shell access on your dedicated server, you can easily change the owner and group (`chown` and `chgrp` commands).  If you don't have shell access, you should be able to change the ownership of the files with an FTP client.  HostGator should be able to help you with this as well.

Comment: Hi chrishajer, Thank you for your message. I noticed that the IP addresses listed above are from Austin TX, (I'm in MD). So the IP addresses look like they are Host Gator's. Would that error get thrown b/c HostGator is trying to fix the 500 Internal Server Error? I don't know jack about this. When I look at the WP folders on the server, I see 755 for the folders and 644 for the files. I haven't checked them all. Any advice would be really appreciated. I've added 50-100 pages in the menu about 10 times only to have it blow up -- max Pain. Thank you!

Comment: I doubt that HostGator is trying to fix anything for you (I could be wrong though - I don't know how detailed your support requests were.)  You were able to check the permissions of files and folders, which look fine to me, but you need to check the ownership and group of the files.  Please post if you have command line access or if you are doing this through an FTP client.

Comment: Hi chrishajer, Thank you for the message. I've got a dedicated server with HostGator. So, I can make any changes that are necessary. I use FTP. (I've never needed to do anything with the command line).

Answer (score 0):

It could be memory issue. You may try increasing [memory available](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP) for php

Also, you may want to server error log or php error logs.

Comment: Hi t-p, Thank you for your message. Do you know how much memory you have allocated for Wp, by any chance? I'm going to ask Host Gator to check the limit. Thank you.

Comment: Hey t-p, I didn't quite understand about the WP memory limit, even after looking at the link that you kindly provided. How do I change the memory limit? Do I just add "define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M');" in the wp-config.php file? Is there a certain place that I need to put this line in the file? Thank you!